# Codeigniter session timeout although clicked through different pages

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have coded a webapp with some pages and I want to have a automatic logout when the session expires. Everything works fine with that, but I noticed that my session expires after the "sess_expiration" time even if I click and visit the different pages.  I normally want  that if one clicks/visits another site the session should begin to count the timeout from the beginning. In my case the visitor can only stay for the "sess_expiration"-time and then the session is expired, even if he clicks and visits the different sites. 
I only initialize the session once in the controllers constructor:

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('session'); 
        }
```

I do not make more than that, except of storing userdata in the session.
What can I do to solve my problem???

Comment: Remove `$this->load->library('session');` from all controllers and include sesion library in autoload.

Answer (score 0):

Put the session class into the autoloader configuration, in application/config/autoload.php:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session' /* , ... */);
```

Then it's available automatically in each controller:

```
$session_id = $this->session->userdata('session_id');
```

and you can initialize the session data after (and only after!) each login.